# How should i version control sub sections of my application?

Tags: laravel, svn, laravel-5

Ok im not 100 percent sure how to word this question but ill give it my best shot. I Have a project that is built in laravel. I am building all the functionaility within "modules" ontop of the codebase that im installing with zip files which contain the relevant models, views and controllers.

In terms of version controlling this and keeping the codebase seperate to the modules as i develop them, is there a best practice i could follow to keep the codebase clear. ...Forks? im just a touch confused at what would i should do in order to say be able to update certain modules versions whilst keeping them seperate to each other.

Here is my best explanation as the structure if you dont understand what i mean

```
Main codebase files --

bla bla bla

= laravel app

mymodule.zip --

-app 
--Http
---Controllers
----myController.php
----andAnotherController.php
 ----theres3ofereController.php
-resources
--views
---mymodule
----index.blade.php
```

This means when the files are applied either manually or through an interface, the files can be just dropped in.

So would i create a seperate folder within the repository for the zip files ? I am essentially asking i guess how to actually make sure i can version them all individually along with the codebase.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: [svn externals](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) may help on this.

Comment: Ahhh interesting concept, is it hard to manage once you have it set up?

Comment: @Jamesmcconnonsince you may need lots of them it may seems confusing, but there should be commands to fetch and commit them all together or individual (It's been a long long time since the last time I've touched SVN).